# Faces Servlet - ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, primefaces

I am developing a sample application using JSF 1.2 and PrimeFaces 3.5. I have RAD in my desktop and created a new dynamic web project. I have written xhtml file with primeface editor tag. But, when I ran the project.. it is throwing "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" for FacesServlet though the servlet exists in the classpath.

My web.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>
    PrimeFacesNew</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
     <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>HelloWorld.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and my HelloWorld.xhtml looks like this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Hello World PrimeFaces</h1>

    <h:form>
       <p:editor value="This is PrimeFace editor" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

I have added below jars in to my classpath..

myfaces-api-2.1.12.jar
myfaces-impl-2.1.12.jar
myfaces-bundle-2.1.12.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar
primefaces-3.5.jar

and when I ran using tomcat 6.0 in RAD, it is throwing below exception..

```
SEVERE: Error loading WebappClassLoader
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@78a978a9
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
Throwable occurred: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4351)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Jun 18, 2013 1:15:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /primefaces threw load() exception
Throwable occurred: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4351)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

The prime face components are also displayed as question mark in the RAD. I tried all the possible solutions in Google, but it hasn't worked for me. Please correct me where I am doing wrong..

Thanks.

Comment: PrimeFaces 3.5 can't run under JSF 1.2, you need JSF 2.X.

Comment: oh I am not aware of that. Let me try adding 2.0 jars and try.

Comment: Alex: I am using myfaces-2.1.2.jar and FacesServlet comes from that jar. So, I guess am using JSF 2.1 jar.

Comment: yes they should provide necessary classes. Are they in the right place? `WEB-INF/lib/` or `<tomcat-root>/lib/` ?

Comment: I have placed them in classpath(properties-> add external jars) and also, I have added them in J2EE module dependencies.

Comment: Sorry don't know RAD :) can't help on that! haha

Answer (score 8):

This issue occured to me because i didn't provide path in Deployement option in properties of project:

Right click on project ---> select "properties" --> Deployement assembly --> "ADD" option --> select "java build path entries" --> select path

Answer (score 2):

Faces Servlet class is not recognized from what you added jars
`myfaces-api-2.1.12.jar, myfaces-impl-2.1.12.jar`

Add below jars to `WEB-INF/lib`

Download [jsf-impl-2.2.5](https://app.box.com/s/vep9ttnphtidcgnmnup7), [jsf-api-2.2.5](https://app.box.com/s/ukt2ybfn9xsqinzw3fuv) or from maven dependency [jsf-api](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-api), [jsf-impl](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jsf-impl.jar and jsf-api.jar since you are using JSF 1.2. Other people are also having this problem read [this](http://www.jvmhost.com/articles/recovery-from-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-faces-webapp-facesservlet) which talks about incompatibility and you specifies the same error which have described here. Hope this helps you resolve this classNotFound error.

Comment: would you please provide a comment as why you marked me down so I can update my answer based on your feedback? (thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0):

if you get `classnotfoundExecption` error for servlets always check have you added the required
libraries in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder...

jars added to build path are not available to server components....

you must explicitly add the jars to `WEB-INF/lib` folder only...

Answer (score -1):

Adding the following dependencies should solve the problem. I was creating a webapp with the JSF dependencies in the web.xml. So, had to add these in pom.xml to get the problem resolved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Use whichever version you require.

Comment: Like in the other answer, with way more modern versions (yours are 8 years old)...